# What's the easiest way to parse numbers in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I've been using java to parse numbers, e.g.

```
(. Integer parseInt  numberString)
```

Is there a more clojuriffic way that would handle both integers and floats, and return clojure numbers?  I'm not especially worried about performance here, I just want to process a bunch of white space delimited numbers in a file and do something with them, in the most straightforward way possible.

So a file might have lines like:

```
5  10  0.0002
4  12  0.003
```

And I'd like to be able to transform the lines into vectors of numbers.

Comment: As a side note, the way you called Java in your post is a unsugared way. Please prefer the sugared way when calling java. `(Integer/parseInt number-string)`, and for instance methods: `(.method obj args)`.

Comment: Adding on top of Rayne's "sweet" suggestion, you can also use `(Integer. number-string)` to parse a into a java.lang.Integer (and similarly for Long, Double, etc...).

Comment: It would seem that the word "easiest" in the title attracted some answers that are easy and unsafe. Please, unless you want to get hacked, use a number parser that can tolerate malicious strings.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use the [edn](https://github.com/edn-format/edn) reader to parse numbers.  This has the benefit of giving you floats or Bignums when needed, too.

```
user> (require '[clojure.edn :as edn])
nil
user> (edn/read-string "0.002")
0.0020
```

If you want one huge vector of numbers, you could cheat and do this:

```
user> (let [input "5  10  0.002\n4  12  0.003"]
        (read-string (str "[" input "]")))
[5 10 0.0020 4 12 0.0030]
```

Kind of hacky though.  Or there's `re-seq`:

```
user> (let [input "5  10  0.002\n4  12  0.003"]
        (map read-string (re-seq #"[\d.]+" input)))
(5 10 0.0020 4 12 0.0030)
```

Or one vector per line:

```
user> (let [input "5  10  0.002\n4  12  0.003"]
        (for [line (line-seq (java.io.BufferedReader.
                              (java.io.StringReader. input)))]
             (vec (map read-string (re-seq #"[\d.]+" line)))))
([5 10 0.0020] [4 12 0.0030])
```

I'm sure there are other ways.

Comment: this method has the useful benefit of properly parsing rational numbers as well. if you modify the re-seq properly (re-seq #"[\d\/\.]+" input)

Comment: beware of read-string

user> (class (read-string "0.5")) = java.lang.Double
user> (class (read-string ".5")) = clojure.lang.Symbol

Comment: In modern times, we have the EDN reader, which would be the right tool for this job.

Comment: Re: "If you're very sure that your file contains only numbers". Whether you are sure (or not) matters not! This is parsing; deal with reality instead of making assumptions. When you parse strings, design your program to tolerate the worst! Go with a safe parsing option instead.

Comment: This is a horrible practice.  `read-string` can *execute* code.  This fact cannot be emphasized enough.  For examples and a good explanation of how bad it can be, even with `*read-eval*` bound to false, see: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/read

Comment: There's also [clojure.edn/read-string](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.edn/read-string) which only parses edn format, and won't execute code.

Comment: Just another "user beware" on this, numbers with a leading zero are treated as octal by the clojure reader, as with many programming langs.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to be safer, you can use Float/parseFloat

```
user=> (map #(Float/parseFloat (% 0)) (re-seq #"\d+(\.\d+)?" "1 2.2 3.5"))
(1.0 2.2 3.5)
user=>
```

Answer (score 26):

Not sure if this is "the easiest way", but I thought it was kind of fun, so... With a reflection hack, you can access just the number-reading part of Clojure's Reader:

```
(let [m (.getDeclaredMethod clojure.lang.LispReader
                            "matchNumber"
                            (into-array [String]))]
  (.setAccessible m true)
  (defn parse-number [s]
    (.invoke m clojure.lang.LispReader (into-array [s]))))
```

Then use like so:

```
user> (parse-number "123")
123
user> (parse-number "123.5")
123.5
user> (parse-number "123/2")
123/2
user> (class (parse-number "123"))
java.lang.Integer
user> (class (parse-number "123.5"))
java.lang.Double
user> (class (parse-number "123/2"))
clojure.lang.Ratio
user> (class (parse-number "123123451451245"))
java.lang.Long
user> (class (parse-number "123123451451245123514236146"))
java.math.BigInteger
user> (parse-number "0x12312345145124")
5120577133367588
user> (parse-number "12312345142as36146") ; note the "as" in the middle
nil
```

Notice how this does not throw the usual `NumberFormatException` if something goes wrong; you could add a check for `nil` and throw it yourself if you want.

As for performance, let's have an unscientific microbenchmark (both functions have been "warmed up"; initial runs were slower as usual):

```
user> (time (dotimes [_ 10000] (parse-number "1234123512435")))
"Elapsed time: 564.58196 msecs"
nil
user> (time (dotimes [_ 10000] (read-string "1234123512435")))
"Elapsed time: 561.425967 msecs"
nil
```

The obvious disclaimer: `clojure.lang.LispReader.matchNumber` is a private static method of `clojure.lang.LispReader` and may be changed or removed at any time.

Answer (score 21):

In my opinion the best/safest way that works when you want it to for any number and fails when it isn't a number is this:

```
(defn parse-number
  "Reads a number from a string. Returns nil if not a number."
  [s]
  (if (re-find #"^-?\d+\.?\d*$" s)
    (read-string s)))
```

e.g.

```
(parse-number "43") ;=> 43
(parse-number "72.02") ;=> 72.02
(parse-number "009.0008") ;=> 9.008
(parse-number "-92837482734982347.00789") ;=> -9.2837482734982352E16
(parse-number "89blah") ;=> nil
(parse-number "z29") ;=> nil
(parse-number "(exploit-me)") ;=> nil
```

Works for ints, floats/doubles, bignums, etc. If you wanted to add support for reading other notations, simply augment the regex.

Answer (score 17):

Brian Carper's suggested approach (using read-string) works nicely, but only until you try and parse zero-padded numbers like "010". Observe:

```
user=> (read-string "010")
8
user=> (read-string "090")
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid number: 090 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

This is because clojure tries to parse "090" as an octal, and 090 is not a valid octal!

Comment: Better suited as a comment on the referenced answer.

Answer (score 15):

Brian carper's answer is almost correct. Instead of using read-string directly from clojure's core. Use clojure.edn/read-string. It is safe and it will parse anything that you throw at it.

```
(ns edn-example.core
    (require [clojure.edn :as edn]))

(edn/read-string "2.7"); float 2.7
(edn/read-string "2"); int 2
```

simple, easy and execution safe ;)

Answer (score 9):

Use `bigint` and `bigdec`

```
(bigint "1")
(bigint "010") ; returns 10N as expected
(bigint "111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111")
(bigdec "11111.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001")
```

Clojure's `bigint` [will use primitives when possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024386/293735), while avoiding regexps, the problem with octal literals or the limited size of the other numeric types, causing `(Integer. "10000000000")` to fail.

(This last thing happened to me and it was quite confusing: I wrapped it into a `parse-int` function, and afterwards just assumed that `parse-int` meant "parse a natural integer" not "parse a 32bit integer")

Answer (score 9):

These are the two best and correct approaches:

Using Java interop:

```
(Long/parseLong "333")
(Float/parseFloat "333.33")
(Double/parseDouble "333.3333333333332")
(Integer/parseInt "-333")
(Integer/parseUnsignedInt "333")
(BigInteger. "3333333333333333333333333332")
(BigDecimal. "3.3333333333333333333333333332")
(Short/parseShort "400")
(Byte/parseByte "120")
```

This lets you precisely control the type you want to parse the number in, when that matters to your use case.

Using the Clojure EDN reader:

```
(require '[clojure.edn :as edn])
(edn/read-string "333")
```

Unlike using `read-string` from `clojure.core` which isn't safe to use on untrusted input, `edn/read-string` is safe to run on untrusted input such as user input.

This is often more convenient then the Java interop if you don't need to have specific control of the types. It can parse any number literal that Clojure can parse such as:

```
;; Ratios
(edn/read-string "22/7")
;; Hexadecimal
(edn/read-string "0xff")
```

Full list here: https://www.rubberducking.com/2019/05/clojure-for-non-clojure-programmers.html#numbers

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much more useful and advocates less bad practices than the top answer.

Comment: To update my answer, with Clojure 1.11, there are now functions in core for some of these: https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/parse-boolean

Answer (score 7):

I find solussd's answer work great for my code. Based on it, here's an enhancement with support for Scientific notation. Besides, (.trim s) is added so that extra space can be tolerated.

```
(defn parse-number
  "Reads a number from a string. Returns nil if not a number."
  [s]
  (if (re-find #"^-?\d+\.?\d*([Ee]\+\d+|[Ee]-\d+|[Ee]\d+)?$" (.trim s))
    (read-string s)))
```

e.g.

```
(parse-number "  4.841192E-002  ")    ;=> 0.04841192
(parse-number "  4.841192e2 ")    ;=> 484.1192
(parse-number "  4.841192E+003 ")    ;=> 4841.192
(parse-number "  4.841192e.2 ")  ;=> nil
(parse-number "  4.841192E ")  ;=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(def mystring "5")
(Float/parseFloat mystring)
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some context by explaining how your answer solve the problem in question, instead of posting code-only answer.