# Parsing integers from strings when validating compojure requests in Clojure

Tags: clojure, compojure

I have compojure based app where I need to parse a request and retrieve parameters that can be numbers. I want to be able to verify that the parameters exist and that they are numbers before actually processing the request. This is what I have so far:

```
(defn get-int [str]
  "Returns nil if str is not a number"
  (try (Integer/parseInt str)
    (catch NumberFormatException _)))

(defn some-request [request]
    (let [some-number (get-int (get-in request [:route-params :some-number])
         other-number (get-int (get-in request [:route-params :other-number])]
    (if (every? identity [some-number other-number])
        (process-the-request)
        (bad-request "The request was malformed")))
```

Is there a better way to do string -> number conversion?

Is there a better way to do request validation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question contains good examples for [parsing numbers in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640169/whats-the-easiest-way-to-parse-numbers-in-clojure). If you are not sure that the string contains a valid number, your approach looks good.

If you can pass the parameters as part of the query string, you could use a route with regex to retrieve the value, e.g.

```
(GET ["/user/:id", :id #"[0-9]+"] [id] 
  (let [num (read-string id)]
    (str "The number is: " num)))
```

The route would only match if the regex conditions are met, therefore you could skip the Integer/parseInt check.

Comment: Probably want to bind `*read-eval*` to false if you're using `read-string` on user input.

Comment: @Huw Won't the fact that the string *id* here matches the regexp *[0-9]+* be enough prevent any mischief in this case though?

Comment: I would swear that that wasn't there when I made my comment :)

Comment: now there's built-in coercion support, `[id :<< as-int]`, see https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Destructuring-Syntax

Answer (score 0):

Use `Long/parseLong` instead of `Integer/parseInteger`. The latter supports only 32 bits, which is often insufficient; for instance, Datomic entity IDs don't fit into Integer.

Never use `read-string` for user input. In addition, you must sanitize user input, removing injected scripts and such. https://github.com/alxlit/autoclave is a good start, although the defaults are arguably too aggressive.