# use-cases for BigInt versus BigInteger in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm looking for guidance on when to use Clojure BigInt versus Java BigInteger in Clojure. Both work just fine, and I am assuming that the main reason to use BigInt is to take advantage of operators like `+` and `=`, which have to be accessed via the Java instance methods `.add` and `.equals`, for instance. But there are few operators, such as `isProbablePrime`, that I can only access from BigInteger.

It seems pretty easy to shift from BigInt to BigInteger or vice versa, but the presence of both makes the use-cases unclear for me. My knee-jerk reaction is just to stick with BigInteger in the absence of clear criteria since some of the suggested usages seem not to work. From [clojuredocs here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/bigint):

```
user=> (def x (bigint 97))
user=> (.isProbablePrime x 1)
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: isProbablePrime for class     
clojure.lang.BigInt  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:53)
```

Comment: After having a look at the source-code of BigInt (https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/BigInt.java) it seems like a BigInt contains both a java.math.Bigint and a long. On the Clojure web-page it says that BigInts keep their type accross all operations. Considering that you can cast easily with .toBigInteger and .fromBigInteger in case that you want to use methods like isProbablePrime, and also considering that it is not easy to construct as java.math.BigInteger, I'd stick to bigint and cast forth and back if necessary (BigInts do this themselves e.g. in .add).

Comment: It's actually `clojure.lang.BigInt/fromBigInteger`; I added an example here http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/bigint

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In "Clojure Programming" by C. Emerick et. al., p.428, there is a sidebar topic, "Why Does Clojure Have Its Own BigInt Class When Java Already Provides One in BigInteger?"

They note two reasons to prefer `BigInt` to Java's `BigInteger`.  First, the latter's `.hashCode` implementation is inconsistent with that of `Long` (the same number expressed in each type gives a different hash value).  This is generally not what you want when comparing equivalent values in e.g. hash maps.

The other reason is that `BigInt`s are optimized to use primitive types when possible, so performance should be better for many cases.

I would use Clojure's numeric types unless you have a good reason not to (your use of `.isProbablePrime` suggests you might have a good enough reason).

Comment: Thank you for that excellent answer. They should write these things in the docstrings.

Comment: I think the continuity of `hash-code` and other operators like `range` is sufficient reason for bias to `BigInt`. I can make a small library of bridging operations for things like `.isProbablePrime`. That strategy will give me a smaller library overall, because in the alternative, I was starting to get sucked into writing an entire math library over `BigInteger`, e.g., `big-range`, `big-le`, etc.