# Low Performance of a factorial function written in Clojure

Tags: ruby, performance, clojure

I am new to Clojure. In experimenting with it I wrote I function to calculate the `n!`. My Clojure code is as follows:

```
(defn factorial
    [n]
    (reduce * (biginteger 1) (range 1 (inc n))))
```

I then ran the following in a repl.

```
(time (factorial 100))
```

And this was the result:

```
"Elapsed time: 0.50832 msecs"
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000N
```

I then created a similar solution in Ruby:

```
def factorial(n)
  start = Time.now.to_f
  (2..n).inject(1) { |p, f| p * f }
  finish = Time.now.to_f
  time_taken = finish - start
  puts "It took: #{(time_taken * 1000)} msecs" 
end
```

The with irb I ran `factorial(100)`
Resulting in:

```
It took: 0.06556510925292969 msecs
 => 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

The performance of the Ruby version seems to be significantly greater, despite most evidence I've seen suggesting that Clojure should have superior performance. Is there something I am misunderstanding or some element of my Clojure solution that would slow it down?

Comment: Try using `bigint` instead of `biginteger`.

Comment: Yep, that worked bigint made the execution much faster.

Comment: Using `time` in this benchmark is severely misleading because of how the JVM "warms up" functions. The clojure example is actually *much* faster than the ruby one, provided you accept the Java Platform designers definition of "fast" as "fast once it's warmed up enough to get compiled"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Miro-benchmarking is very often misleading and in general it's rather hard to get it right. The easiest way to get reasonably close in clojure (that I've found is the criterium library (thanks Hugo!). If I start with an ugly version of calculating factorial by simply looping I get about 3 ns.

```clj
user> (defn loopy-fact [x]
        (loop [y x
               answer-so-far 1]
          (if (pos? y)
            (recur (dec y) (*' answer-so-far y))
            answer-so-far)))
#'user/loopy-fact

user> (loopy-fact 100)
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000N
```

And then let's benchmark it:

```
user> (criterium.core/bench #(loopy-fact 100))
WARNING: Final GC required 11.10521514596218 % of runtime
WARNING: Final GC required 1.069604210579865 % of runtime
Evaluation count : 12632130300 in 60 samples of 210535505 calls.
             Execution time mean : 2.978360 ns
    Execution time std-deviation : 0.116043 ns
   Execution time lower quantile : 2.874266 ns ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 3.243399 ns (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 1.844334 ns

Found 4 outliers in 60 samples (6.6667 %)
    low-severe   2 (3.3333 %)
    low-mild     2 (3.3333 %)
 Variance from outliers : 25.4468 % Variance is moderately inflated by outliers
```

If we then make the code look better by using a normal Clojure Style, with map and reduce, and no effort at making it fast.

```clj
user> (defn mapy-fact [x]
        (reduce *' (range 1 (inc x)))
#'user/mapy-fact

user> (mapy-fact 100)
933262154439441526816992388562667004907159682643816214685929638952175999932299156089414639761565182862536979208272237582511852109168640000000000000000000000N
```

Now let's find out how that compares:

```
user> (criterium.core/bench #(mapy-fact 100))
Evaluation count : 8674569060 in 60 samples of 144576151 calls.
             Execution time mean : 5.208031 ns
    Execution time std-deviation : 0.265287 ns
   Execution time lower quantile : 5.032058 ns ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 5.833466 ns (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 1.844334 ns

Found 4 outliers in 60 samples (6.6667 %)
    low-severe   1 (1.6667 %)
    low-mild     3 (5.0000 %)
 Variance from outliers : 36.8585 % Variance is moderately inflated by outliers
```

It's a bit slower, but **only slower by two nanoseconds**.

This is much better than it looked in your test because criterium runs the function enough times for the JVM's Hotspot compiler to get around to compiling it and inlining all the parts. This demonstrates why **microbenchmarks can be very misleading on the JVM**. and you should almost certainly keep criterium around for such cases.

PS:  `*'` is the "auto promoting" multiplication opperator, it will promote it's types to big-integer or big-decimal as required

Answer (score 6):

`BigInteger` comes from java, while `BigInt` is implemented in the Clojure's core. Right off the bat, that comes with some costs related to [interopability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_interoperability).

---

Additionally, `BigInt` is represented as either [a `long` or a `BigInteger`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/BigInt.java#L54). Whenever possible, [the `long` is used](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/BigInt.java#L143). However, if any operation makes it [overflow](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/BigInt.java#L145), the resulting new `BigInt` [will use it's `BigInteger`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/BigInt.java#L148). Java's `long` maps to the native architecture's implementation, hence is significantly faster. This is similar to Ruby's magic conversion between `Fixnum` and `Bignum`.

Since you use small numbers almost exclusively (1 to 100 and a good chunk of the intermediate products), you can get a significant performance boost.

Comment: I found an answer discussing the difference between the use of biginteger and bigint http://stackoverflow.com/a/18024386/2801159

Answer (score 2):

Further to [@ndn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41103662/1562315):

You can gain further speed by type-hinting the argument `n`:

```
(defn factorial [^long n]
  (reduce * (bigint 1) (range 1 (inc n))))
```

Comment: with type hinting I get a runtime of: `Execution time mean : 5.197206 ns` and without I get `Execution time mean : 5.349130 ns` with a standard deviation of 0.34 ns, so the difference made by the type hinting is in the noise. This is because the Clojure compiler does type inference and will figure it out on it's own.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt The Clojure compiler can't know that `n` is a whole number, since it need not be. Is it not more likely that Hotspot is doing the good deed?