# Sum of numbers in a list from user input

Tags: list, clojure

Question from a total newbie with Clojure. Task is pretty simple, but I'm having hard time finding the best way to do this - I need to set up input, where user could give me a list (user should determine how long) of natural numbers and the program should just return a sum of these numbers.

Maybe this is totally wrong already:

```
(defn inputlist[naturallist]
  (println "Enter list of natural numbers:") 
  (let[naturallist(read-line)] ))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
> lein new app demo
> cd demo
```

Edit the `project.clj` and `src/demo/core.clj` so they look as follows:

```
> cat project.clj

(defproject demo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.reader "1.1.3.1"] ]
  :main ^:skip-aot demo.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})

> cat src/demo/core.clj 

(ns demo.core
  (:require
    [clojure.tools.reader.edn :as edn]
    [clojure.string :as str]  ))

(defn -main []
  (println "enter numbers")
  (let [input-line (read-line)
        num-strs   (str/split input-line #"\s+")
        nums       (mapv edn/read-string num-strs)
        result     (apply + nums) ]
    (println "result=" result)))
```

with result

```
> lein run
enter numbers
1 2 3     <= you type this, then <enter>

input-line   => "1 2 3"
num-strs     => ["1" "2" "3"]
nums         => [1 2 3]
result       => 6
```

You may wish to start looking at some beginner books as well:

- [Brave Clojure](https://www.braveclojure.com/)
- [Living Clojure](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920034292.do)
- [Programming Clojure](https://pragprog.com/book/shcloj3/programming-clojure-third-edition)
- [The Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)

Comment: Hi!
Tried this code, firslty had errorr egarding usage of tupelo, added dependencies, now i'm getting :
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to resolve symbol: defproject in this context, 
compiling:(C:\Users\...\project.clj:1:1)

Comment: I updated the example.  Make `project.clj` and `src/demo/core.clj` look like the example & it should work for you.

Comment: Works fine now! Thanks a lot! 
Got everything but the last 3 lines of project.clj.
Will google it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to do this I can think of is

```
#(apply + (map #(Integer/parseInt %) (re-seq #"\d+" (read-line))))
```

This defines an anonymous function which:

- (read-line) - reads a line of text, hopefully containing numbers separated by non-numeric characters. So you type in something like "123 456 789"
- (re-seq #"\d+" ...) - uses the regular expression `\d+` to search for strings of consecutive digits. Each string of consecutive digits is added to a sequence, which is subsequently returned. So, for example, if you type in `123, 456, 789` the `re-seq` function will return the sequence `'("123" "456" "789")`.
- (map #(Integer/parseInt %) ...) - invokes the anonymous function `#(Integer/parseInt %)` for each element in the list returned by the `re-seq` invocation, creating another list of the results. So if the input is `'("123" "456" "789")` the output will be `'(123 456 789)`.
- (apply + ...) - applies the `+` function to the list of numbers, summing them up, and returns the sum.

Et voila! The end result is, you type in a string of numbers, separated by non-numeric characters, you get back the sum of those numbers. If you want to be a little neater, promote code re-use, and in general make this a bit more useful you could break this up into separate functions:

```
(defn parse-string-list [s]
  (re-seq #"\d+" s))

(defn convert-seq-of-int-strings [ss]
  (map #(Integer/parseInt %) ss))

(defn sum-numbers-in-seq [ss]
  (apply + ss))
```

Invoking this in a Lisp-y way would look something like

```
(sum-numbers-in-seq (convert-seq-of-int-strings (parse-string-list (read-line))))
```

or, in a more Clojure-y way

```
(-> (read-line)
    (parse-string-list)
    (convert-seq-of-int-strings)
    (sum-numbers-in-seq))
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Clojure—and StackOverflow!

Here's how to do it:

```
(defn input-numbers-and-sum []
  (print "Enter list of natural numbers: ")
  (flush)
  (->> (clojure.string/split (read-line) #"\s+")
       (map #(Integer/parseInt %))
       (reduce +)))
```

Here's how it works:

- Calling `print` rather than `println` avoids printing a newline character at the end of the line. This way, the user's input will appear on the same line as your prompt.
- Since there was no newline, you have to call `flush` to force the output buffer containing the prompt to be printed.
- [`split`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/split) splits what the user typed into a sequence of strings, divided where a regular expression matches. You have to say `clojure.string/split` rather than just `split` because `split` is not in Clojure's [core library](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core). `clojure.string/` specifies [the library](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string). `#"\s+"` is a [regular expression](https://clojure.org/reference/other_functions#regex) that matches any number of consecutive whitespace characters. So, if your user types `"  6 82   -15   "`, `split` will return `["6" "82" "-15"]`.
- [`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) calls the standard Java library function [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) on each of those strings. `Integer/parseInt` is Clojure's [Java interop](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop) syntax for calling a static method of a Java class. The `#(...)` is terse syntax that defines an anonymous function; the `%` is the argument passed to that function. So, given the sequence of strings above, this call to `map` will return a sequence of integers: `[6 82 -15]`.
- [`reduce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) calls the [`+`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/+) function repeatedly on each element of the sequence of integers, passing the sum so far as an argument along with the next integer. `map` and `reduce` actually take three arguments; the next paragraph tells how the third paragraph gets filled in.
- [`->>`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) is the "thread-last macro". It rewrites the code inside it, to pass the output of each expression but the last as the last argument of the following expression. The result is:
  `(reduce + (map #(Integer/parseInt %) (clojure.string/split (read-line) #"\s+")))`
  Most people find the version with `->>` much easier to read.

That might seem like a lot to do something very simple, but it's actually bread and butter once you're used to Clojure. Clojure is designed to make things easy to combine; `map`, `reduce`, and `->>` are especially useful tools for hooking other functions together.

I've included links to the documentation. Those are worth a look; many contain typical examples of use.

There are other ways to parse numbers, of course, some of which are shown in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2640169/1393162). What I've written above is an "idiomatic" way to do it. Learn that, and you'll know a lot of the everyday, must-know techniques for programming in Clojure.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, readline is the correct way to do it. 
But each element from `readlines` is essentially an instance of `java.lang.Character` , and since you want the sum, you'd prefer to convert them to integer before summing the elements of list.

```
(defn input-list
  []
  (print "Enter list of natural numbers") 
  (let [nums (read-line)] 
    (reduce + (map #(Integer/parseInt %) (clojure.string/split nums #"\s+")))
```

This might not be the most idiomatic way to do it, but feel free to tweak it.

Also, please do clean up on your variable/function names.

**Edit** : `(Integer/parseInt %)` might cause an error if used directly since the input is an instance of characters, not string. So we can use `clojure.string/split` to convert user input to a sequence of strings, and use `Integer/parseInt %` for conversion.

In fact, a more readable version can be written using thread-first macros :

```
(defn input-list []
  (print "Enter list of natural numbers: ")
  (->> (clojure.string/split (read-line) #"\s+")
       (map #(Integer/parseInt %))
       (reduce +)))
```

This is a more clojurey way to do it.

Comment: Got an error. Some trouble with convertion? :
ClassCastException java.lang.Character cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: Yup, user input is sequence of characters and needs to be converted to sequence of string before using `#(Integer/parseInt %)` . Have fixed it. Thanks for pointing out.  @kjankausks

Comment: Now it works! Easy to understand as well, thanks, @namc!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about negative scenarios (wrong input, syntax issues), the quickest solution would be to evaluate the user's input putting it into parens:

```
(defn sum-ints []
  (let [input (read-line)
        ints (read-string (str "(" input ")"))]
    (reduce + 0 ints)))
```

Usage:

```
user=> (sum-ints)
1 2 3 4 5
15
```

The `read-string` function evaluates an text expression `(1 2 3 4 5)` in that case. Since numeral literals turn into numbers, the result will be just a list of numbers.